# How to set audio to play when video starts for amp-wistia-player

Tags: amp-html

How do I set the Wistia player in AMP to have sound on by default? Currently, when the video plays, you need to tap the audio button in order for the sound to work.

Comment: Have you set the video to auto-play?

Comment: So I've made a 'cover' so that when it's clicked, the video starts to play...

Answer (score 0):

You can't set audio on when on mobile if You want to set the wistia player (or any other player) to auto it will play only with muted sound with the option to turn it on by the user, the web limitations:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

You can set it to autoplay only if You mute the video when autoplayed...

I have made it work with AMP and wistia (need to add an id to wistia player and use it in the lightbox {on="tap:video_lightbox_5, trainVid.play"} where {tranVid} is the id of the wistia player in general same as using the AMP video via documentation: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-video/). 
This works only if You set video to be mutable or *play sound when available- and autoplay option checked in wistia itself.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

silentAutoPlay=false&autoPlay=true would work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).